# How do I use the result of one function in another function to get the value stored in a cell in another sheet in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

In my current sheet I have some numbers in a column, which represent the row which I want to get the data from in another sheet. And I want to get it from the same column in which I am using the function...

I know using =Sheet1!A1 for instance gets me what is in A1 on Sheet1

and

=CONCATENATE("A",A1) being on sheet two, brings me back A + whatever value is stored in A1 on sheet number two... for simplicity let's say it's a one... so it would return A1

I am on Sheet2

I'm trying

=Sheet1!CONCATENATE("A", A1)

but the formula contains an error, I've tried rewriting this in many ways but it never works... any idea what the correct syntax I need is?

Greatly appreciated!

THanks

Comment: See INDIRECT [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258053/how-to-make-a-reference-to-a-cell-of-another-sheet-when-the-sheet-name-is-the-v?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Magicianeer said, you have to use the `INDIRECT` function. For your example:

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Sheet1!","A",A1))
```

Should give the results you need.

However, it's a bit lengthy, and you can use `&` instead of `CONCATENATE`, and you can directly use `Sheet1!A`:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A"&A1)
```

What is evaluated in the brackets is `Sheet1!A1`, and `INDIRECT` converts this from text to a reference.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

=CONCATENATE("A", Sheet1!A1)