# Referring to cell in another worksheet, but specifying the cell number from a certain cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Sorry for the confusing title, I'm pretty confused myself.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is:

```
='Sheet 3'!(F2 in current worksheet)
```

So in Cell F2, I have a value of "G69"

The end result I want to achieve is

```
='Sheet3'!G69
```

On cell F2, my formula is:

```
=CONCATENATE("G", E2)
```

Bonus point if you can do this...:

```
='Sheet 3'!(Value of Concatenate("G",A1)
```

THANK YOU FOR ANY HELP YOU CAN PROVIDE!

**EDIT: =INDIRECT("'Sheet 2'!F2")is the answer I was looking for. Thanks guys!**

Comment: Can you please add more information ?

Comment: What type of information do you need??

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions05.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using the value in a cell as a cell reference in a formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150861/using-the-value-in-a-cell-as-a-cell-reference-in-a-formula) or [How to make a reference to a cell of another sheet, when the sheet name is the value of a cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258053/how-to-make-a-reference-to-a-cell-of-another-sheet-when-the-sheet-name-is-the-v)